# jquery Use two done callbacks in same function, one with datatype json one without

Tags: jquery, ajax

Trying to use two `done` callbacks in a jQuery function. One is a data type JSON, the other is not.
The first calls a php function for its `data` that is not a JSON array. The second I want would call a JSON encoded array from the same php call. I need to pass the array of the ID's to another function

Is this possible? Something like this

```
function func1() {

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
    data: {
      action: 'myphp'
    }
  })

  .done(function(data) {
    jQuery('#adivID').html(data);
  })
  .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    alert(error);
  })

  dataType: 'JSON',
  .done(function(data) {
    ids: id;
    func2(data.ids);
  })
}
```

EDIT 1 - attempt at two end points

```
function func1() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
    data: {
      action: 'myphp'
    }
  })

  .done(function(data) {
    jQuery('#adivID').html(data);
  })
  .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    alert(error);
  })

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {
        action: 'myphp',
        ids: id;
    }
  })   
  .done(function(data) {
    func2(data.ids);
  })
}
```

PHP

```
function phpfunctionname{
$id= wpdb->get_results("SELECT id from mycats");
$ids .='';
foreach($id = $value){
ids=$value-.id;
};
echo json_encode(array('ids' => $ids));
};
```

Comment: The code in your question is syntactically invalid. Could you please fix it up? Adding proper indents would also make it much more readable

Comment: Run your code through https://beautifier.io/ for formatting. It won't fix your broken code though

Comment: Looks to me that OP is posting code snippets (not SO snippets) in an attempt to demonstrate what they are trying to achieve

Comment: In short, no.  You can't have jquery call two different `.done()` with different data types as the (return) dataType is set before making the ajax call.  In your second (json) `.done()` you could JSON.parse(data).  But `data` in the first is html.  How will your single end point with a single call return two different data types?  It's not jquery that determines the data type, it's the server; jquery just converts it for you (eg parses json if you say it's json that's being returned, so you get an object instead of a json string)

Comment: `One is a data type JSON, the other is not.`... One ajax call = one response having one data type. You should do 2 request to two diferent endpoint to have two different results.

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you for that thoughtful answer. Is there a good method to achieve something like this then? I am not married to the idea above. I am needing to use the html data that is coming in the `data` but form that extract `id's` out of a `foreach` loop in the php. Then I need to pass along those `ids` to another jquery function

Comment: @louyspatricebessete do you mean like the edit 1 posted above in the OP?

Comment: The `EDIT 1` make a lot more sense... About the syntax, at least. You now have 2 different requests with 2 different `data` sent. -- SO does it work? Errors in console?

Comment: @louyspatricebessette it does not work. It tells me the id isnt defined

Comment: if I add the `ids` to the func1 (ids) then it does pass but isnt pulling out the encoded data from the php. I have specifically `json_encode($ids)` in the php file. According to the .log, it is pulling all the data anyway

Comment: Post the PHP code... Maybe it will enlight the issue here.

Comment: @louyspatricebesstte added the php

Comment: "html from the server" then "extract IDs in the php" - these are clearly two separate actions - you can't tell jquery to magically reformat your data just by setting a different dataType.  You could make one call that returns *data* then build the html client-side, or parse your html client-side.  Alternatively, one call to get data (eg IDs) then 2 separate calls to get html/full-data passing in those IDs.

Comment: Perhaps the best option would be to make a single call that returns both html *and* json in a json wrapper, eg `{ "html": your_html, "data": { json_data } }` (demonstration only - then you get both back in a single call and your first used `result.html` and the second uses `result.data`

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you. For this would I need to make an html string out of the php or do all the above in the jquery? Don't suppose there is anything we can do about the way Louys seems to enjoy putting down people here? Does really feel like a good community spirit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can nest ajax callbacks. But first we may want to review what we're talking about here.

`JSON` stands for `javascript object notation`. It isn't a data type, it's a way to encode a javascript object into a text string so it can be easily stored/transferred.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

`jQuery` is a javascript library. It's basically sytactical sugar for vanilla javascript. https://jquery.com/

`PHP` is a sever side language used for taking client requests, doing stuff with it, and returning a response. You don't call php functions from the client. You make a request and the sever decides how to respond. https://www.php.net/

That out of the way, if you want different data back from the same url, you would have to add that in your options object and then handle that server side. Client side would be something like this:

```
jQuery.post(my_ajax.ajax_url, { action: 'myphp', return_type: 'string' })
  .done(function(data) { //data will be a string
    jQuery('#adivID').html(data);

    //this part doesn't make sense, because if the data is a string,
    //it won't have an 'id' property. But maybe in your actual code this
    //does make sense. So this is just an example of how nesting works.
    jQuery.getJSON(my_ajax.ajax_url, { ids: data.ids, return_type: 'json' })
      .done(function(json) { //json will be an object
        //do stuff with the object
      })
      .fail(function() {
        //response was probably not properly json formatted
      });
  })
  .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    alert(error);
  });
```

[jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) and [jQuery.getJSON()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) are just short hands for [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), as they require less parameters, and unless you're doing something more complex, keeps your code more readale.

Edit (since you added your php code):

I'm not familiar with wordpress, and it took a few reads to try and figure out what your code is doing. But what I gather from the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/), you might want something like this:

```
$ids = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id FROM mycats", ARRAY_N); //returns an indexed array of ids

switch($_POST["return_type"]) {
  case "string": //returns a comma separated string of ids
    echo implode(", ", $ids);
    break;
  case "json": //returns a json array of ids
    echo json_encode($ids);
    break;
}
```

But again, the `getJSON()` is going to fail because the `post()` is going to return a string. It's tough to suggest code without knowing exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish. It's probably also worth noting that in php an [object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) is different from an [associative array](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_associative.asp) is different from an [indexed array](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_indexed.asp). Also, all variables start with a `$`. `wpdb` != `$wpdb` If you haven't lost several hours because of this, you haven't written enough php haha.

Comment: Thank you for posting a thoughtful answer

Comment: when trying to use the example above, I am getting a "data not defined" error? Given that this is a very different way from what I am used to, I am not sure what that is telling me , other than the obvious- the data isnt defined. The error is coming off the second nested  call where it says `data.ids` Does seem the second portion is running before the 1st though