# jquery preventing the second nested function from running first

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a nested AJAX call that I am trying to ensure the jQuery.getJSON call doesn't run before the jQuery.post. It keeps running the second before the first which is why I assume I am getting an error about "data not being defined" for the second call.

```
jQuery.post(my_ajax.ajax_url, { action: 'myphp', return_type: 'string' })
  .done(function(data) { 
    jQuery('#adivID').html(data);

   
    jQuery.getJSON(my_ajax.ajax_url, { ids: data.ids, return_type: 'json' })
      .done(function(json) { 
        //do stuff with the object
      })
      .fail(function() {

      });
  })
  .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    alert(error);
  });
```

So I tried:

```
jQuery.post(my_ajax.ajax_url, { action: 'myphp', return_type: 'string' })
  .done(function(data) { 
    jQuery('#adivID').html(data);

    window.setTimeout(function () {
    jQuery.getJSON(my_ajax.ajax_url, { ids: data.ids, return_type: 'json' })
      .done(function(json) { 
       
      })
      .fail(function() {

      });
        
    }, 3500);
  })
  .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    alert(error);
  });
```

This tells me that the `window.setTuneout(...)` fail is not a function and it doesnt prevent the second from loading before the first.

Comment: Can you mark out exactly what is running first and what isn't?

Comment: absolutely,, just did

Comment: But `jQuery.getJSON` is nested inside `jQuery.post` so how is it running first?

Comment: not sure but the log shows its response first on the console

Comment: Related [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65984992/jquery-use-two-done-callbacks-in-same-function-one-with-datatype-json-one-witho)